# Fast filtering of a IEnumerable based on a list of tuples in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my C# application I have a list of tuples, a sort of a reference database, as follow:

```
public List<Tuple<DateTime, double, int>> MyList = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double, int>>();
```

I also have `IEnumerable<Custom>` that holds 3 values, `x` and `y` and `z`. I need to iterate over this IEnumerable and check if the x-y-z values are "present" in the reference database with certain criteria.
To do this, I am using LINQ (as it is very easy to work with) to count how many tuples remain in the reference list after the custom filtering

```
foreach (Container c in IEnumerable.V)
{
        var res = MyList 
            .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item1)
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1 >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-c.x))
            .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item3)
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item3 == c.z)
            .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item2)
            .Where(tuple => somemath(tuple.Item2, c.y) <= 1)
            .Count();

        if (res != 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
// do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Although this works just fine, it is too slow for my purpose (10-30 ms, I need it at least 100 times faster!).
What would be a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have the `OrderBy`s?

Comment: There's no point in the three `OrderBy` entries as only the last one will be applied in the end (though all will cost time). No ordering will affect the `Where`. Furthermore, why do you have three `Where` sections instead of just one big one? It also seems like you want `Any` instead of `Count`.

Comment: Did you measure performance? What does `somemath` do? Is it a bottleneck? Maybe you also might gain some speed if you optimize this method.

Comment: Ok, my mistake I guess. I thought that the `Where` would be consecutive, so to make each `Where` faster I was first sorting the data.

Comment: @SomeBody I dee, `somemath` takes some ns, just some multiplications/divisions

Comment: Do you know the shape of the data? Can you predict which one of the three Where clauses filters the most data? Could it be that one of those 3 could already return 0 results? If you create a simple benchmark with DotNetBenchmark it's easy to create those different scenarios and test your performance.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, right, Any would do it much better, thanks. Regarding the `Where`. You wrote that no ordering will affect the `Where`. Would you then suggest to break the LINQ into 3 "filtering"? Like res1, res2, res3, each with a pair of `OrderBy` and `Where`?

Comment: My point is that `.Where` will run for all items that you iterate (and using Count will iterate all of them). Ordering is going to be rather expensive if it's not doing anything productive.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I have a rough idea of the data, they are coming from a real time stream of data, and creating a blackmark is not so easy. I have the feeling that `somemath(tuple.Item2, c.y) <= 1` would filter out most of the data, followed by `.Where(tuple => tuple.Item3 == c.z)`

Comment: I do not want to post it as an answer myself, but I have ran some quick tests and this is the fastest way for my data ```var res = MyList .Where(tuple => PPM(tuple.Item2, c.y) <= 1 && (tuple.Item3 == c.z) && (tuple.Item1 >= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-c.x))).Any();```, which is a bit faster than 3 consecutive `.Where`

Answer (score 2):

Since the first criterion is to compare time, I believe a better strategy would be to order both the list and the input sequence by time and to walk through them in lockstep. Designing such an algorithm would be a bit more engaged for me to post here.

The other problem is that you are effectively testing whether there are *any* items in the list that match the current input element. You should not waste resources counting them to only test one bit of information.

Those are the two principal sources of CPU waste in your code.